# Get-AzSnapshot : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter Specified method is not supported

Tags: azure, powershell

My requirement is to delete snapshots that are older than 7 days with the name like *appname-*. but before deleting i need to fetch the snapshot data with some names. 
the script executes and provides some snapshot datas inidtially but in middle thhows below error.
could someone help me on this.why i got this error message and how to fix

=========================================================================

> Get-AzSnapshot : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ResourceGroupName'. Specified 
>   method is not supported.
>   At line:6 char:39
>   +     Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotNam ...
>   +                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzSnapshot], ParameterBindingException
>
> ## + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.GetAzureRmSnapshot

```
$snapshotnames = (Get-AzSnapshot).Name

foreach($snapname in $snapshotnames)
{
    $resourceGroupName = (Get-AzResource -Name $snapname).ResourceGroupName
    Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapname  | Where-Object {($_.TimeCreated -eq (Get-Date).AddDays(-3))} <#-and ($_.Name -like '*-2019_*') } | select Name,TimeCreated -Verbose 

}
```

Comment: Does `Get-AzResource -Name $snapname` ever result in multiple items? If that happens, then `$resourceGroupName` will become an object array. Then you will have this problem.

Comment: i want the $resourceGroupName variable to hold ResourceGroup names value. How can i convert the object array variable to string of values?

Comment: will piping $resourcegroup variable to Out-String resolves this issue? Like below
  $resourceGroupName | Out-String

Comment: $snapshotnames = (Get-AzSnapshot).Name


foreach($snapname in $snapshotnames)
{
    $rg = (Get-AzResource -Name $snapname).ResourceGroupName
    $resourceGroupNames = $rg | out-string
     foreach($resourceGroupName in $resourceGroupNames){
        Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapname  | Where-Object {($_.TimeCreated -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)) -and ($_.Name -like '*apr-2019_*') } | select Name,TimeCreated
     } 
}

Comment: I guess no. Piping to Out-String will through an error as below


Get-AzSnapshot : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
At line:10 char:9
+         Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Snapsho ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzSnapshot], JsonReaderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.GetAzureRmSnapshot

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-AzResource -Name $snapname).ResourceGroupName
```

This will return a collection of `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResource` objects, each of which have the `ResourceGroupName` property.  You need to add logic to filter the `$resourceGroupName` variable to only contain the one you are looking for.

Comment: will piping $resourceGroupName variable to Out-String resolves this issue? Like below
  $resourceGroupName | Out-String

Comment: $snapshotnames = (Get-AzSnapshot).Name


foreach($snapname in $snapshotnames)
{
    $rg = (Get-AzResource -Name $snapname).ResourceGroupName
    $resourceGroupNames = $rg | out-string
     foreach($resourceGroupName in $resourceGroupNames){
        Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapname  | Where-Object {($_.TimeCreated -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)) -and ($_.Name -like '*apr-2019_*') } | select Name,TimeCreated
     } 
}

Comment: I guess no. Piping to Out-String will through an error as below


Get-AzSnapshot : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
At line:10 char:9
+         Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Snapsho ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzSnapshot], JsonReaderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.GetAzureRmSnapshot

Comment: If you wanted to get the snapshot for each resource group, then you would just need to add a foreach loop for getting the snapshot in your original example.  You do not need to do anything anywhere with `Out-String`.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. 
Here i need to list the snapshots older than 3 days. To get the snapshot detail, i need to fetch its  ResourceGroup name  first. So   only i added this line of code. ie..
(Get-AzResource -Name $snapname).ResourceGroupName

Comment: $snapshotnames = (Get-AzSnapshot).Name

 foreach($snapname in $snapshotnames) { 
$resourceDetails = (Get-AzResource -Name $snapname) l select Name, ResourcegroupName
$SnapDetails = $resourceDetails.Name
$SnapRGs = $resourceDetails.ResourcegroupName
Forever($SnapDetail in $SnapDetails){
  Forever($SnapRG in $SnapRGs){
      
 Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $SnapRg -SnapshotName $SnapDetai | Where-Object {($_.TimeCreated -eq (Get-Date).AddDays(-3))} -and ($_.Name -like '*-2019_*') } | select Name,TimeCreated -Verbose }
}
}
}